# Darken lines on drawing

Tags: svg, drawing

[image]Need to darken the lines on this drawing. I know nothing about editing or graphics. Eventually I need to make an svg of this drawing to make an acrylic embosser to use on fondant

Comment: "Eventually I need to make an svg of this drawing to make an acrylic embosser to use on fondant" - do this first, it will give you the ability to have higher quality darkened lines

Comment: Please include what software you're trying to use and what you've tried so far

Comment: Hey Zach I’ve tried adjusting the saturation vibrance and sharpening. I’ve tried playing with an app called vectornator but I honestly am a novice. A friend suggested Inkscape but I don’t have a PC or laptop so all I have is my iPhone to try with apps on

Answer (score 1):

A simple technique using **Photoshop** which works often is to ...

- Duplicate the layer.
- Set duplicate layer blend mode to `Multiply`.
- Repeat until you're happy.

I'm sure the same could be accomplished in many different applications.

---

For *this* image specifically.. using Photoshop, I would first correct the **Levels** of the image (`Image > Adjustments > Levels`) to make the white actually white and bring the black point in towards the actual data on the histogram...

[image]

Then `Filter > Other > Minimum`, which will allow you to "beef up" the lines....

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I use PaintShop Pro from Corel, which has similar features to Scott's recommendation for Adobe Photoshop. The results are slightly better than the faded original.

[image: darker image]

but I think you have a bigger challenge in converting a bitmap to an SVG, if you are limited to a portable cellular communications device.

I've created a trace of the bitmap and [stuffed it into my dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ac0ouhaxdxarctg/stocking%20trace.svg?dl=0). The result is a double line for each of the lines you have in your original image, as the trace performs the work on the outside of each line as well as the inside of each line.

[image: bitmap trace]

Some manual intervention is needed if you require single line tracing.